# Sharing an arraylist of bytearray between threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have one thread T1 producing some content (`ArrayList<byte[]>` type) and want a second thread T2 to read the most recent content produced by T1. How do I share this data between threads safely to ensure that T2 gets the latest content while ensuring T1 is not currently writing to the variable? I looked at the producer consumer model, but it doesnt seem like what I need since I only need to get the latest content.

Comment: You synchronize.  Exactly how that might look in your case is unclear, because the details of what you're trying to do are unclear.  This is where a [mcve] comes in handy.

Comment: I do not see how this is not a producer consumer model

Comment: Did you look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html ?

Comment: Do you have to use an ArrayList?  [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) is pretty much made for this.

Answer (score 1):

Update the content in a synchronized block or use the volatile keyword when declaring the variable. More info on volatile here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is described almost exactly in the sample code for [java.util.concurrent.Exchanger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html).